# Extend object wrappers for modern primitives

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

Starting from ES6 classes can extend special objects like functions, arrays and primitive's wrappers. It's simple: just write a class that extends corresponding type and use it:

```js
class MyNumber extends Number {
  constructor() {
    super(42)
  }
  
  square() {
    return this ** 2
  }
}

var x = new MyNumber()

console.log(typeof x, x + "", x.square() + "")
```

But EcmaScript also has some new types like `Symbol` and `BigInt`. They still have a non-primitive wrapper types, but you can't use them as constructor and need to explicitly wrap primitive into an object:

```js
var x = BigInt("42")
var y = Object(x)

console.log(typeof x, x + "", x + 1n + "")
console.log(typeof y, y + "", y + 1n + "")

try {
  var z = new BigInt("42")
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}
```

What if I want to extend such wrapper? Defining a class works fine, but if I try to create an object, it throws on `super` call:

```js
class MyBigInt1 extends BigInt {
  constructor() {
    super("42")
  }
}

try {
  var x = new MyBigInt1()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}

class MyBigInt2 extends BigInt {
  constructor() {
  }
}

try {
  var x = new MyBigInt2()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-symbol-constructor):

> The `Symbol` constructor […] is not intended to be subclassed.

And similarly from [the BigInt proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-bigint/#sec-bigint-constructor):

> The `BigInt` constructor is not intended to be used with the `new` operator or to be subclassed.

Instantiating primitive wrappers is already bad enough, don't go extending them.

A hack would be to not call `super()` (which you cannot prevent from throwing), but create the object yourself (without `new`) and then set its prototype to your custom one. Just like you already did it in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58207509/1048572) :-)

Comment: Read on... ... "may be used as the value of an `extends` clause" ...

Comment: Interesting, but why such solution was made?

Comment: @Qwertiy To prevent people from subclassing stuff they should have been wrapping. See [this issue on the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/98) for a more extensive rationale.

Comment: And you can find even more rationale at https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/13

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution, but still searching for a better way:

```js
class MyBigInt extends BigInt {
  constructor() {
    var res = Object(BigInt("42"))
    Object.setPrototypeOf(res, new.target.prototype)
    return res
  }
  
  square() {
    return this ** 2n
  }
}

var x = new MyBigInt()

console.log(typeof x, x + "", x.square() + "")
```

And same approach with `Symbol`

```js
class MySymbol extends Symbol {
  constructor(description) {
    var res = Object(Symbol(description))
    Object.setPrototypeOf(res, new.target.prototype)
    return res
  }
  
  smth() {
    return `(${this.description})`
  }
}

var x = new MySymbol("qqq")

console.log(typeof x, x.description, x.smth())

var y = { [x]: 42 }

console.log(y[x], y[x.toString()])
```