# Comparing Custom Strings(classes extending String class) using ==

Tags: javascript, string, comparison

I was wondering, if there are any ways on how to compare 2 custom string objects which are instances of classes which extend String, using `==` doesn't work and it always returns false.

I have tried using valueOf but with no luck, the method gets never called if both operands are objects.

See an example below

```js
class MyString extends String {
  doSomething(someData) {
    return doSomethingWithData(this, someData);
  };

  valueOf() {
    console.log('valueOf called');
    return this.toString();
  };
};
```

When doing `console.log(new MyString('hi') == 'hi');`, I Get

```
valueOf called
true
```

But When doing `console.log(new MyString('hi') == new MyString('hi'));`, I Get `false`.

So, the valueOf gets never called and the comparison blindly returns false, is there any possible way to fix it?

Comment: [Don't extend `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58207487/1048572). [Don't create String objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5750656/1048572). And no, [you cannot overwrite equality between objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19620667/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi I cannot not extend or not use the String objects, as I'm working on a library, and I need to add custom methods to the object.

Comment: Well no, you shouldn't need to do that. Provide static helper methods working on ordinary strings.